# Usabilidade do useState e useEffect no react-TS

Tags: react

Me perdoem de antemão caso tenham gafes no código rs.
Estou praticando react-TS criando um "deck maker" de Yu-gi-oh!. Por enquanto fiz apenas uma listagem de todas as cartas do jogo, mas me deparei com um problema. Usei o useEffect pra poder executar a chamada da API e inserir os dados para uma constante com o useState. Se eu tento listar os cards como componente em tela me ocorre um erro, porém se eu faço uma função pra listar os cards no console o resultado ocorre como o esperado.

Código com o print no console:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Loading } from '../components/Loading'

interface AllCardsProps {
    data: [
        {
            name: string
        }
    ]
}

export function Home() {
    const [allCards, setAllCards] = useState<AllCardsProps>({} as AllCardsProps)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php')
        .then(response => {
            setAllCards(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    function clickHere() {
        allCards.data.map(card => {
            console.log(card.name)
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="w-screen h-screen">
            {
                !allCards ?
                <Loading />
                : <button onClick={clickHere}>It's time to duel</button>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Código tentando exibir os cards em tela:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Loading } from '../components/Loading'

interface AllCardsProps {
    data: [
        {
            name: string
        }
    ]
}

export function Home() {
    const [allCards, setAllCards] = useState<AllCardsProps>({} as AllCardsProps)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php')
        .then(response => {
            setAllCards(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    function clickHere() {
        allCards.data.map(card => {
            console.log(card.name)
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="w-screen h-screen">
            {
                !allCards ?
                <Loading />
                : allCards.data.map(card => {
                    return (
                        <p key={card.name}>{card.name}</p>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Erro ao tentar exibir o nome dos cards em tela:

```
@react-refresh:278 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Home (Home.tsx:34:33)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:20)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26096:20)
```

Poderiam me dar alguma ideia, correção ou dica do que fazer a respeito?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parece que o erro está ocorrendo porque você está tentando acessar a propriedade "data" de "allCards" antes de ela ter sido definida. Isso acontece porque a chamada à API é assíncrona, então, quando o componente é renderizado pela primeira vez, "allCards" ainda é undefined.

Uma forma de resolver isso seria adicionar uma verificação antes de acessar a propriedade "data" para garantir que ela foi definida antes de ser usada. Algo como:

```js
{
    !allCards ?
    <Loading />
    : allCards.data && allCards.data.map(card => {
        return (
            <p key={card.name}>{card.name}</p>
        )
    })
}
```

Dessa forma, o código dentro do "map" só será executado quando allCards.data for verdadeiro, e evitará que o erro ocorra.

Outra forma é usar o useEffect para garantir que a chamada da API foi concluída antes de tentar acessar allCards.data, e adicionar um estado que guarda se a chamada já foi concluída, e verificar esse estado antes de renderizar os dados.

```js
const [allCards, setAllCards] = useState<AllCardsProps>({} as AllCardsProps)
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php')
    .then(response => {
        setAllCards(response.data)
        setIsLoading(false)
    })
}, [])
```

```js
    return (
        <div className="w-screen h-screen">
            {
                isLoading ? <Loading /> : allCards.data.map(card => {
                    return (
                        <p key={card.name}>{card.name}</p>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
```

Espero que isso ajude!

Comment: Agora eu entendi, e funcionaram ambos o métodos, valeu mano!